# Symmetry Group Regular Tetrahedron

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

[image]

Looking for some help of how to do this, which could also be expanded to other shapes.

Thanks.

Comment: Check something here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_symmetry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Any symmetry of the tetrahedron must map vertices to vertices, and is completely determined by this mapping from vertices to the vertices. Label the vertices $A,B,C,D$ and consider the permutations of these vertices.  Eliminate those that do not correspond to geometric symmetries of the tetrahedron.  For example, if you rotate the tetrahedron so that $A$ and $B$ exchange places, then $C$ and $D$ also exchange places.

Since each symmetry is completely determined by its action on the four vertices, once you have identified the permutations of the vertices, you can forget about the rest of the tetrahedron and think only about the permutations.

Obtain an actual tetrahedron; tetrahedral dice are available online or in game stores.  If you can't find an actual tetrahedron, make one. If you can't make one, find a cube (such as a die) and color four alternate corners with a red marker.  These are the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, and any symmetry of the tetrahedron is therefore also a symmetry of the cube.

Comment: So you don't include reflections then? Yes, they require you to break the atoms, but mathematically that's ok.

Comment: In order to actually find the rotations, it may be useful to find the actual rotation axes. These are either through a vertex and the middle of an opposing side, or through the middles of two opposing edges. If you want to take reflections into consideration: just find one reflection first (if possible as permutations of vertices) and consider what happens when composing this with the different rotations.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not sure what you mean.  Nothing I said rules out reflections.

Comment: There is a reflection that keeps C and D in place but exchanges A and B.

Comment: That is true, but I did say that in that example I was considering a rotation.

Comment: Fair enough! The elimination process is then very modest in the sense that all 24 permutations of the 4 vertices occur :-)

Comment: Yes, I considered that, but OP had also expressed an interest in other polyhedra, for which the elimination process is nontrivial, so I left it as it was.